# ngStorage: When to use LocalStorage and when to use SessionStorage

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, ng-storage

I'm planning to use gsklee/ngStorage in my application and according to the docs you inject sessionStorage and localStorage into your module/controller. My question is in which situations should I use sessionStorage and when should I use localStorage? Also is the session going to be dead when the user closes his browser?

Comment: Most of your question is easily answered by reading the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Thank you, that seems right